# Unable to reference value of for loop variable multiple times

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, iteration, command-prompt, directory-structure

I'm working on a batch script to reformat the directory of different suppliers, and I'm having issues with a for loop.

So far, the script takes the original directory that contains files (SampleDirectory), and copies over the first level of folders, which is made up of supplier names, to "NewDirectory" which will be the target directory that the reorganized files will be moved to.  What I'm looking to do next is iterate through the paths in "NewDirectory" and find the name of a supplier, which is the lowest level directory.  From there, I'd use the supplier name, and append it to the end of the NewDirectory path so I can create subdirectories within the new folder.

```
:start
MKDIR "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory"
ROBOCOPY "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\SampleDirectory" "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory" /E /LEV:2 /XF
PAUSE

FOR /D %%G IN (C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\*) DO (
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO G:         %%G
CALL SET DirPath=%%G
CALL SET DirFolder=!DirPath!
:GetFolder
CALL SET GetFolderTemp=!DirFolder:*\=!
IF NOT !GetFolderTemp!==!DirFolder! (
    SET DirFolder=!GetFolderTemp!
    GOTO :GetFolder
)
ECHO DirPath:   !DirPath!
ECHO DirFolder: !DirFolder!
ECHO G:         %G%
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
)
ECHO !
PAUSE
```

The issue I'm running into now is that I am only going through the first folder and getting it's title.  I feel as though I've overwritten the variable for the for loop that is causing it to end early.

Output:

```
G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms
DirPath:   C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms
DirFolder: Arrington Arms
G:         %G
```

Intended Output:

```
G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms
DirPath:   C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms
DirFolder: Arrington Arms
G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms

G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms - Copy
DirPath:   C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms - Copy
DirFolder: Arrington Arms - Copy
G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Arrington Arms - Copy

G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Bosch
DirPath:   C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Bosch
DirFolder: Bosch
G:         C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\Bosch
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know that `goto` breaks the loops? Also there's no need for `call` in those `set` statements.

Comment: %G% is an environmental variable.  Did you mistype and meant to have %%G from the FOR variable?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `%%~nxG`

Comment: @wOxxOm, I didn't know that, that's probably what it was.

Comment: @Squashman, thank you, that was what I was looking for.  And I tried a bunch of different combinations of %%G to see if it would work.

Thanks, Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
:start
MKDIR "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory"
ROBOCOPY "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\SampleDirectory" "C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory" /E /LEV:2 /XF
PAUSE

FOR /D %%G IN (C:\webnet\Guy\113015\NewDirectory\*) DO (
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO G:         %%G
SET DirPath=%%G
SET DirFolder=%%~nxG
ECHO DirPath:   !DirPath!
ECHO DirFolder: !DirFolder!
ECHO G:         %%G
ECHO.
ENDLOCAL
)
PAUSE
```